# What is the most idiomatic way to emulating Perl's Test::More::done_testing?

Tags: perl, unit-testing, scope

I have to build unit tests for in environment with a very old version of `Test::More` (perl5.8 with `$Test::More::VERSION being '0.80'`) which predates the addition of `done_testing()`.

Upgrading to newer Test::More is out of the question for practical reasons. And I am trying to avoid using `no_tests` - it's generally a bad idea not catching when your unit test exits prematurely - say due to some logic not executing when you expected it to.

**What is the most idiomatic way of running a configurable amount of tests**, assuming no `no_tests` or `done_testing()` is used?

---

*Details*:

My unit tests usually take the form of:

```
use Test::More;
my @test_set = (
   [ "Test #1", $param1, $param2, ... ]
  ,[ "Test #1", $param1, $param2, ... ]
  # ,...
);

foreach my $test (@test_set) {
    run_test($test);
}

sub run_test {
    # $expected_tests += count_tests($test);
    ok(test1($test)) || diag("Test1 failed");
    # ...
}
```

The standard approach of `use Test::More tests => 23;` or `BEGIN {plan tests => 23}` does not work since both are obviously executed before `@tests` is known.

---

My current approach involves making `@tests` global and defining it in the `BEGIN {}` block as follows:

```
use Test::More;
BEGIN {
    our @test_set = (); # Same set of tests as above
    my $expected_tests = 0;
    foreach my $test (@tests) {
        my $expected_tests += count_tests($test);
    }
    plan tests => $expected_tests;
}
our @test_set; # Must do!!! Since first "our" was in BEGIN's scope :(
foreach my $test (@test_set) { run_test($test); } # Same
sub run_test {}  # Same
```

I feel this can be done more idiomatically but not certain how to improve. Chief among the smells is the duplicate `our @test_test` declarations - in `BEGIN{}` and after it.

---

Another approach is to emulate `done_testing()` by calling `Test::More->builder->plan(tests=>$total_tests_calculated)`. I'm not sure if it's any better idiomatically-wise.

Comment: What are the practical reasons for not upgrading Test::More?

Comment: By "no_tests" I presume you mean "no_plan"?  It works fine if your test dies prematurely.  The only condition where "no_plan" becomes a problem is if your test exits early and normally.  Try it.

Comment: @Schwern - it's a core module. Getting software Engineering to approve it will take more time and effort (write-ups, presentations, convincing management, company-wide testing) than I can justify to management when the only trade-off is neater unit tests

Comment: @Schewrn - sorry, this (if your test exits early and normally) was exactly what I actually meant when I clumsily worded it as "dies prematurely". I have updated the question.

Comment: @DVK Presentations? Write ups? Management involvement? To upgrade a Perl module? I'm sorry. I'd call those "impractical reasons". :-/  If your upgrade process is that sluggish, consider simply having a Perl library directory specific to your project where you can install and overlay whatever extras and upgrades your project needs independent of everyone else.

Comment: @Schwern - I don't make the world. I just live in it. But in case you wonder why it's so ridiculous, please consider that the Perl codebase in question runs a large part of the major corporation. Change management is a Big Deal.

Comment: @DVK Yes, having everyone depend on the same set of Perl libraries leads to crippling inflexibility as you're experiencing. Thus per-project libraries to overlay and upgrade as necessary. Its not the best solution, but its a cheap, safe, local way to get some flexibility back.  (And don't cop out of your role in improving your own position)

Comment: @DVK => if you move the `our @test_set;` before the `BEGIN` block, you don't need to declare it `our` again.  you could also qualify the name `@::test_set` and omit the `our` lines entirely. `@test::set` would also work, and almost looks clean ;-)

Comment: Political implications of module upgrades aside, I would recommend *against* trying to hack in `done_testing` and just use `no_plan`.  You're likely to spend more time working on the hack, fiddling with plan counts, and introduce more instability into the tests then you'd ever lose with the very rare failure no_plan misses.  And then, of course, you have to modularize the hack to use it in more than one place at which point you might as well have a local copy of Test::More.  Is this a real problem you've encountered or have you been reading anti-no_plan propaganda?

Comment: There are lots of big corporations that depend on Perl but don't have your political problems. There are also lots of small companies that do have your problems. The problem is not the size of the enterprise.

Comment: @brian - touché. It's endemic to large companies with centralized software engineering and tool engineering teams, which not all of them have (I worked for both ends of the spectrum, actually). For small companies, it's actually makes a lot less sense for a variety of reasons

Comment: @Schwern - I wasn't even aware there existed "anti-no_plan propaganda" :) But I could write one since as I said I have actually had fairly spectacular Big Testing Fails (due to bugs in complex test drivers) which would have masked major code issues... except the test bugs were uncovered by "not enough tests ran" despite not having a single test failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a closure to return the test sets, which allows you to avoid the awkwardness of a package variable? Here's an illustration:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Test::More;

BEGIN {
    my @ts = (
        [ 'Test 1', 1, 1 ],
        [ 'Test 2', 3, 3 ],
    );

    plan tests => scalar @ts;

    sub test_sets { return @ts }
}

for my $ts ( test_sets() ){
    run_test($ts);
}

sub run_test {
    my ($msg, $val, $exp) = @{shift()};
    is $val, $exp, $msg;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't hack around old versions, just ship with a copy of Test::More.  It has no dependencies.  Simply install it into `t/lib` of your distribution (you can build it and then copy `blib/lib`) and then `use lib "t/lib"` in your tests.

Comment: @Schwern - software engineering actually looks at test code. Were I to do that, the **best** case scenario would be a big chew-out by managing director running that team. Sadly, I play by corporate game rulebook. If you want to know what happens one one doesn't, ask Mr. Original Just Another Perl Hacker (http://www.lightlink.com/spacenka/fors/) :(

Comment: @DVK Chewed out for what?  The copy of Test::More is specific to your tests.  It has no effect on anyone else's code.

Comment: @Schwern - using local copies of CPAN modules is... how should I put it... frowned upon.

Comment: @DVK: What's funny is that corporate types will use a quite similar case to what they are rejecting in order to shoot you down: "If you put a special Test::More here, suppose we wanted to upgrade Test::More later, code depending on that might be out of sync with other code... blah blah blah..." and you may even see this "lack of understanding" on your next review.

Comment: @DVK They won't let you upgrade modules and they won't let you use local copies, even in tests? You have a problem and its not Test::More. Don't let fear keep you from revising a broken system, especially if its just policy. And don't invoke Randal's case as some sort of justification for inaction, making a local install of a Perl module does not apply. Push back. Point out that you're wasting time hacking around missing Test::More features and having to write dodgy versions. Point out that real productivity and quality is being lost because local copies are "frowned upon".

Comment: I can identify with DVK here... some folks just have an inherent distrust of modules and libraries. Don't ask me why.

Comment: There are always companies looking for Perl programmers. If you don't work at a company that lets you work smartly, find a company that does.

Comment: @brian - the pros of this company majorly outweigh the cons. Thus I'm posting "How to take a best approach to work around a minor problem that I already know how to fix" as opposed to careeroverflow.com candidate questions :) .

Comment: @Shwern - is there any data (I think you're the owner) as far as backwards compatibility of Test::More and company? The request to upgrade might go through a lot smoother if it's backwards compatible 100% (both by design, and by current version passing all unit tests from older one :) )

Comment: @DVK Incompatibilities for Test::More are logged in the Changes file as "Features Changed" or "Feature Changes". They are all extremely minor and mostly deal with error message formatting. Occasionally a bug fix will reveal failing tests that passed before. I refer to this as "fixage". Examples are the use_ok fix in 0.71 and cmp_ok fix in 0.85_01. New versions will not pass the old version's tests, they are not all blackbox nor were they all correct. Test::More is one of the most vital, widely used, derived from and best tested modules on CPAN. It even tests 3rd party dependent modules.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly idiomatic approach:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Test::More;
use List::Util 'sum';

sub count_tests {1}

BEGIN {
    plan tests => sum map {
        count_tests($_)
    } @test::set = (
        [ "Test #1", '$param1, $param2, ...' ],
        [ "Test #1", '$param1, $param2, ...' ],
    )
}

run_test($_) for @test::set;
```

Using a fully qualified name avoids the need for `our`, you could also use `@::test_set` if you are worried about putting something in the `test::` package.  And using `map` and `sum` from `List::Util` shortens the code in the `BEGIN` block a bit.  The functional form also inverts the flow of data, which allows all of the tests to be declared at the end, keeping the `plan` call at the top, to remind why the `BEGIN` block was used in the first place.

Comment: Eric - I like the idea of putting something in a test package. +1

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is to calculate the plan based on a table of tests, that's trivial.

```
use Test::More;

my $Asserts_Per_Set = 10;
my %Tests = (
    "Test #1" => { foo => "bar", this => "that" },
    "Test #2" => { foo => "yar", this => 42     },
    ...
);

plan tests => keys %Tests * $Asserts_Per_Set;

for my $name (keys %Tests) {
    run_tests($name, $Tests{$name});
}
```

If for some reason `run_tests` needs to run a variable number of tests based on the data, make use of `skip` rather than an `if` so it always runs a consistent number of tests.

```
SKIP: {
    skip "Can't run foo test on frobnitz", 2 if $test->{foo} and $test->{frobnitz};

    is foo(), $test->{foo};
    is bar(), $test->{foo} + 9;
}
```

For anything more complicated, add to the plan as you go by making use of `BEGIN` blocks.

```
use Test::More;
my $Count;

BEGIN { $Count += X }

...run X tests...

BEGIN { $Count += Y }

...run Y tests...

BEGIN { plan tests => $Count }
```

This at least keeps the test count calculations in line with the block of tests its calculating or, instead of having it all in one big unmaintainable blob at the top.  Its all highly visible and requires no magic except `BEGIN`.

Incidentally, new versions of Test::More have `subtest` to better handle the problem of breaking up a test into multiple plans.